# bib references appear ending with a comma

Tags: biblatex

[image]

I'm citing these references from Google Scholar, but why is the format wrong, ending with a comma instead of a period, does anyone know how to fix it?

```
@inproceedings{garcia2018few,
  title={Few-shot learning with graph neural networks},
  author={Garcia, Victor and Bruna, Joan},
  booktitle={International Conference on Learning Representations},
  year={2018}
}
@inproceedings{finn2017model,
  title={Model-agnostic meta-learning for fast adaptation of deep networks},
  author={Finn, Chelsea and Abbeel, Pieter and Levine, Sergey},
  booktitle={International conference on machine learning},
  pages={1126--1135},
  year={2017},
  organization={PMLR}
}
@inproceedings{ravi2017optimization,
  title={Optimization as a model for few-shot learning},
  author={Ravi, Sachin and Larochelle, Hugo},
  booktitle={International conference on learning representations},
  year={2017}
}
```

My question concerns a project that I've stripped down, below is the overleaf link for the project. Currently the project still has comma errors and one of the references cannot be successfully compiled.
https://www.overleaf.com/8218265618cwxvxbpkzhkx

Comment: Welcome to tex.se.

Comment: Can you add a small compilable code example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: The output is controlled by the bibliography style you use. We need to know more about your document setup before we can help you. Please show us a small example document that we can compile and that reproduces the issue with as little code as possible.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I edited and released my project. Please help me to find out what went wrong

Comment: Please do not post the example document off-site. The Overleaf link can only be viewed with an Overleaf account. Instead reduce your document so far that it can be posted directly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly due to the compatibility problem between my template style file and my reference format. I have solved it by changing the style file